# Codazzi-Mainardi Equation & Field Equations

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

So the Codazzi-Mainardi Equation implies
$$
P^{\alpha \mu} n^\nu G_{\mu\nu}=D^\alpha K - D_\mu K^{\alpha \mu} \tag{1}
$$
where $G_{\mu\nu}$ is the Einstein-tensor, $D_{\mu}=P_{\mu}^\alpha \nabla_\alpha$ is the covariant derivative on the hypersurface and
$$
\gamma_\mu^\nu = P_\mu^\nu = \delta_\mu^\nu + n_\mu n^\nu
$$
is the induced metric or projector onto the spacelike hypersurface respectively ($n^\mu$ timelike, $n^2 = -1$).
Also $K=K_\mu^\mu$ and
$$
-2 K_{\mu\nu} = \gamma_\mu^\alpha \nabla_\alpha n_\nu + \gamma_\nu^\alpha \nabla_\alpha n_\mu = {\cal L}_{n} \gamma_{\mu \nu}
$$
is the extrinsic curvature with ${\cal L}_n$ being the Lie-derivative.
Using the field equations on equation (1), one obtains
$$
D_\mu \left( \gamma^{\alpha \mu} K - K^{\alpha \mu} \right) = 8\pi {P^{\alpha\mu}n^\nu T_{\mu\nu}} \
$$
where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor.

These are actually only 3 momentum constraint equations in numerical relativity, and I'm just confused as apparently the $\alpha=0$ relation is trivial.

Is it?

The only way I manage to view this is by looking at this in Minkowski-Space i.e. for an arbitrary symmetric tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ I have $n^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$, $n_\mu=(-1,0,0,0)$ and then
$$
P^{\alpha\mu}n^\nu T_{\mu\nu} = \left( g^{\alpha \mu} + n^\alpha n^\mu\right) T_{\mu 0} = T^\alpha_0 - n^\alpha T^0_0 
$$
which vanishes trivially for $\alpha=0$.

So now generally?

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:computational-physics] tag for questions that aren't actually about simulations/models.

Comment: But it is related in a very direct sense..

Comment: While possible having arisen during a computational problem, your question isn't about the simulation but about whether a particular term in an equation is identically/trivially zero.